# Fixed list another list with multiple passes

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a fixed list where I want to add another list with multiple passes. What would be a proper function for this?

```
list1 = {2, 3}; addList = {4, 3}; numSteps = 5;
l2 = list1 + addList;
l3 = % + addList;
l4 = l3 + addList;
l5 = l4 + addList;
l6 = l5 + addList;
{list1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6}
```

> ({{2, 3},
>     {6, 6},
>     {10, 9},
>     {14, 12},
>     {18, 15},
>     {22, 18}})

Comment: `Table[{2, 3} + k {4, 3}, {k, 0, 5}]`?

Comment: `Array[{2, 3} + {4, 3} (# - 1) &, 6]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this way:

```
list1 = {2, 3}; addList = {4, 3}; numSteps = 5;
positions = NestList[addList + # &, list1, numSteps]
points = {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[positions]};
Graphics[{points}, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 20/25, 
 PlotRange -> {{25, 0}, {0, 20}}]
```

[image]